# Rails3 OAuth Plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-provider

Hi I installed OAuth Plugin on my Rails 3 app to turn it into an OAuth Provider.

I followed the instruction from https://github.com/pelle/oauth-plugin under Rails 3.

But, under the instructions it says the following:

It requires an authentication framework such as acts_as_authenticated, restful_authentication or restful_open_id_authentication. *It also requires Rails 2.0.*

I am puzzled by the fact that it says Rails 2.0 is required. Do I have to install Rails 2.0 as well somehow? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it shouldn't.

Make sure you have something higher than 0.4.0 in your Gemfile, as the instruction say

```
gem "oauth-plugin", ">= 0.4.0.pre1"
```

Rails 3 will never allow you to load Rails 2, its going to implode.